# For a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, does $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$ have any particular meaning?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I was recently reading Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak. Spivak defined whether a function is differentiable using linear transformations, which makes sense to me. However, just out of curiosity, I was wondering about this:

> For a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, does $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$ have any particular meaning? Specifically, if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\|f(x) - f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$ exists, does $f$ have to be differentiable at $a$? And if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, does $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$ exist? Here $\| x\|$ is just the $L^2$ norm.

I know if $n=m=1$, this is the absolute value of the derivative, but I really cannot think of what this does in the multivariable case. I tried some algebraic manipulation, but it really did not lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the limit exists, it doesn’t imply differentiability, even in the special case $n=m=1$. There are obvious counterexamples here. However, if you assume the limit is in particular $0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ with $Df_a=0$.

Conversely, if you assume $f=(f_1,\dots, f_m)$ is differentiable at $a$ (which is equivalent to each $f_i$ being differentiable at $a$… see the subsequent sections of the text), then:

- in the case $n=1$, the limit exists and  is equal to the $2$-norm of the vector $(f_1’(a),\dots, f_m’(a))\in\Bbb{R}^m$.
- if $n\geq 1$ **and** $Df_a=0$, then the limit in question exists and is $0$ (by definition of what it means to have $Df_a=0$).
- However, in the case $n>1$ the limit in question need not exist in general. This is because differentiability alone tells allows you to write $f(a+h)-f(a)=Df_a(h)+\rho(h)$, where $\rho$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\|\rho(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0$. So, $\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)\|}{\|h\|}=\left\|Df_a\left(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\right)+\frac{\rho(h)}{\|h\|}\right\|$. The second term we know tends to $0$ as $h\to 0$, but we know nothing about the limit of $\left\|Df_a\left(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\right)\right\|$. Try to see if you can come up with a concrete counterexample now (and note where you use $n>1$).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x=a$ with $df(a) = A$ (a linear operator from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$), we have
$f(x) = f(a) + A (x-a) + o(\|x-a\|)$, and
$$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\|f(x) - f(a)\|}{\|x - a\|} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\|A(x-a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$$
But that limit only exists if $A$ is a scalar multiple of an isometry.