# Differential of a function as a limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential

Based on intuitive definitions of the differential of a function, it seems to me that for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ something like
$$
df(a) = \lim_{|r| \to 0} \frac{|f(a+r)-f(a)|}{|r|}
$$
should hold for $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, although this may be an abuse of notation. I haven't been able to prove it from the usual definition I've encountered that the differential is the linear map defined by
$$
df(a)(v_1, \dots, v_n) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_k}(a)v_k, \dots, \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_k}(a)v_k\right).
$$
Does any such limit definition of the differential of a function exist?

My motivation for asking this is from Narasimhan's *Analysis on Real and Complex Manifolds* where he uses in a proof that for $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $(dg)(0)=0$ implies that there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $0$ such that for any $x,y \in W$,
$$
|g(x)-g(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x-y|.
$$
This would follow directly from the limit formula that I gave, but is there a more rigorous way to show this?

Edit: Of course, in the book $g$ is also specified to be continuously differentiable on an open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ containing the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such formula holds because the thing on the right is a (limit of) numbers, while $df(a)$ is a linear map. THese are different objects. If you remove the norm in the numerator, $\frac{f(a+r)-f(a)}{\|r\|}$, the numerator is not a linear map, so you can’t say much about its limit. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4603899/568204) for some related discussions.

The definition of $df_a$ is that (when it exists) it’s the unique linear map such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-df_a(h)\|}{\|h\|}&=0.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
So, if $df_a=0$, then plug in $0$ above to get
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)\|}{\|h\|}&=0.
\end{align}

But, the claim you make is wrong; the Lipschitz estimate **does not** follow from merely the limit condition (even when $n=m=1$). Consider the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{align}
f(x)&=
\begin{cases}
x^2&\text{if $x\in\Bbb{Q}$}\\
0&\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, $f$ is differentiable only at the origin and $f$ is not even continuous away from the origin, with $f’(0)=0$. However, if the Lipschitz estimate were true in a neighborhood of the origin, then $f$ must be continuous in a neighborhood of the origin, which we just said is not the case (if you wanted to be fancy, you could also invoke Rademacher’s theorem and get a contradiction).

If however you assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of the point $a$, then you can obtain this Lipschitz estimate using the mean-value inequality and the fact that $df_a=0$, and hence in a neighborhood, $\|df_x\|$ can be made small. Note that in general, if you’re trying to get information about the function at different points using only information about the derivative, then the mean-value inequality is often lurking in the shadows.

---

One very minor remark I’d make is that I’d rather not say that

> the differential is the linear map defined by
> $$
> df(a)(v_1, \dots, v_n) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_k}(a)v_k, \dots, \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_k}(a)v_k\right).
> $$

I would prefer to say that this is a *consequence* of the definition $(*)$. Because if you define $df_a$ by this formula, then you’d have to define partial derivatives first, and one runs the very widespread and common risk of thinking that partial derivatives are the key concept, and $df_a$ is a secondary concept, when it is completely the other way around.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thanks! The definition (*) was what I was missing, that's definitely a more fundamental perspective than the one I gave (which was all I had in the book).